# Why does a forward declaration not fix the circular dependency?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, circular-dependency

I have three classes: a `TopClass` which contains an instance of a `BottomClass` pointer. The `BottomClass` contains a pointer to a `HelperClass`. The `HelperClass` keeps a pointer to the `TopClass`. Circular dependency pops up and a forward declaration is needed in the `HelperClass`.

All of this is illustrated with the following code snippets:

```
#include "BottomLevel.h"

namespace foo
{
  class TopLevel
  {
  private:
    BottomLevel* item;
  };
}
```

-

```
#include "HelperClass.h"

namespace foo
{
  class BottomLevel
  {
  private:
    HelperClass* item;
  };
}
```

-

```
class TopLevel; // forward declaration here

namespace foo
{
  class HelperClass
  {
  public
    HelperClass(TopLevel* item);
  };
}
```

The issue comes when trying to do things in the implementation file. If I `#include "TopClass.h"` in the cpp file, I get compilation errors stating "overloaded member function not found -- use of undefined type '`TopLevel`'" (ERRORS C2511 and C2027).

Then, if I don't do the `#include` I'm still left with C2027 errors because I try to use the forward declared type.

I just know there is a method to fix this, I'm sure I've done it before, but I can't for the life of me remember what I'm supposed to do. Any help please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're forward declaring `TopLevel` outside the `foo` namespace so the compiler is never finding the class `foo::TopLevel`.

Try moving the forward declaration of `TopLevel` inside the `foo` namespace.

Comment: /facepalm -- You sir, have humbled me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a forward declaration of the form

```
namespace foo {
class TopLevel;
class BottomLevel;
class HelperClass;
}
```

Then the order wont matter [because you use pointers]

Comment: Tune in next week for another exciting episode of Stack Overflow, where Shynthriir finds out exactly what he has to put!